# how to send file and form data in angularjs to node.js server?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

hello I am creating mean application for video upload form. I struck at one place when i do post request in angular js to my api then no data is going to my controller.Where am i doing wrong??

```
<form ng-submit="uploadComplete(form)" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm"  ng-controller = "addCtrl">

<div class="form-group">
  <label >Title</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "form.title" name="title" placeholder="Enter Title">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label >Description</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" ng-model= "form.description"  name ="description" rows="5" id="comment" placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label >Author</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "form.author"  name ="author" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Enter Author Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label >duration</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "form.duration"  name ="duration" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Enter duration Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label >ispublic</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "form.public"  name ="public" id="exampleInputPassword1" >
</div>



<input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileChanged(this)" id="userfile" name="userfile" multiple/>


  <input type="submit" name="" value="submit">
```

my angular controller is

```
function addCtrl($scope, $filter, editableOptions,$http, editableThemes,$window,$uibModal, baProgressModal) {
      $scope.fileChanged = function(elem){
        $scope.files = elem.files;
        $scope.$apply();
      }
  $scope.uploadComplete = function(f){

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    format: 'json',
    url: '/api/add-video',
    headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
    data: JSON.stringify({
      title: f.title,
      description: f.description,
      duration: f.duration,
      author:f.author,

      file:$scope.files,
      ispublic:parseInt(f.public)
    }),
    transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                    formData.append(key, value);
                });

                var headers = headersGetter();
                delete headers['Content-Type'];

                return formData;
            }

  })
  .then(function(success) {
    console.log("hit " + JSON.stringify(success));
    // $window.location.reload()
  }, function(error) {
    //console.log("not hit " + JSON.stringify(error));
  });

   }
  console.log($scope.files[0].name);
  console.log(parseInt(f.public));
  }

  }
  })();
```

and my api/url which is part of server side

```
app.post('/api/add-video', addVideoHandler);
function addVideoHandler(req, res) {

  var data = {
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    author: req.body.author,
    duration: req.body.duration,
    file: req.body.file,
    ispublic: req.body.ispublic
  }
console.log(data);

}
```

I already use all node package in above url file which i didn't mention.Why i didnt getting all data in console it displays :

```
 { title: undefined,
  description: undefined,
  author: undefined,
  duration: undefined,
  file: undefined,
  ispublic: undefined }
```

Where am I doing wrong ??
Please guide me.Thankyou

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: all field are undefined while these all values are display in angular controller

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a directive as below

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
        function fn_link(scope, element, attrs) {
            var onChange = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            element.on('change', function (event) {
                onChange(scope, { $files: event.target.files });
            });
        };
        return {
            link: fn_link
        }
    }])
```

then replace input type=file to

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="fileId" accept="image/*" file-model="myFiles($files)"/>
```

and then in your controller add this

```
var formData = new FormData();
        $scope.myFiles = function($files) {
            formData.append('img', $files[0]);
}
```

**Replace 'img' to a name which you want it as in backend**
**Add each and every values with keys in formData to send**
as

```
formData.append('title', form.title);
formData.append('description', form.description);
formData.append('author', form.author);
formData.append('duration', form.duration);
formData.append('public', form.public);
```

and your $http method

```
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/add-video',
    headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            },
    data: **formData**),
```

**Node Side**
then use multer diskStorage as to upload file to server

```
var uploadMulter = multer.diskStorage({
     destination: function(req, file, callback) {
         callback(null, "./UploadDir");
     },
     filename: function(req, file, callback) {
         callback(null,  Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
     }
 });

var upload = multer({ storage: uploadMulter });
```

**./UploadDir** is the destination folder where you want to upload your file

and finally your router

```
app.post('/api/add-video',  upload.single('img'), addVideoHandler);
```

now if you want to upload a single file use **upload.single('img')
** or for multiple use **upload.array('img',3)** here 3 files will be uploaded. change as you want.

**This is my first answer on StackOverflow :-)**

if your destination dir UploadDir is not accessible try to join by

```
app.use('/UploadDir', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'UploadDir')))
```

**try this $http method if that dont work**

```
$http.post('/api/add-video',formData,{headers:{'Content-Type': undefined}})
```

**Change you Controller as**

```
.controller('addCtrl', function($scope,$http){
var formData = new FormData();
 $scope.myFiles = function($files) {
  formData.append('img', $files[0]);
  }
$scope.uploadComplete= function(form){
  formData.append('title', form.title);
  formData.append('description', form.description);
  formData.append('author', form.author);
  formData.append('duration', form.duration);
  formData.append('public', form.public);
  $http.post('/api/add-video',formData,{headers:{'Content-Type': undefined}}).then(function(res){
    alert("Correctly Done")
   }, function(err){
   alert("Error check console in browser");
    console.log(err)
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: try this to know how its going --- **app.post('/api/add-video',  upload.single('img'), function(req,res){
console.log(req.body);
console.log(req.file);
console.log(req.files);
});**

Comment: it still display all data undefined:-(

Comment: did you set headers:{content-type : **undefined**}?

Comment: yes i write the code as u give detail nd also set content-type : undefined

Comment: what your sending in $http - data?

Comment: i console form data it is also undefined

Comment: and try to console.log(req.body) in app.post as i gave you

Comment: bro i do but formData is undefined so no logic to see in app.post

Comment: it didnt append in form data

Comment: Try to append with $scope like formData.append('title', $scope.form.title); and formData will never will displayed try to log your $scope.form

Comment: same no change.formData is still undefined. while i console.log(form.title).It work fine

Comment: remove enctype="multipart/form-data"  from your form

Comment: still same.now it display like this FormData {} and it is empty object

Comment: try that last one $http method

Comment: try now the last one

Comment: bro you didn't understand my problem.i want to print formdata in angular controller but it shows empty object.so it also show the same after app.post as no data is contained by formdata in angular controller in which we send **data**:formData//it is empty.

Comment: Bro fromData never show its content and if you want to show just value then display That variable which you have passed as a parameter in angular or by $scope like $scope.form , formData will never describe its property

Comment: just console $scope.form and formData this two variables you will get what you want

Comment: yeah $scope.form display whole object and formData is display emptyObject.as u said i console.log(req.body) on app.post `{}
{ title: undefined,
  description: undefined,
  author: undefined,
  duration: undefined,
  file: undefined,
  ispublic: undefined }
` it display like this on console

Comment: thanks bro.I get it but still it still it didnt show data on node side

Comment: i console.log(req.body) all fields are undefined

Comment: Hey Andrew! Did you find the answer? I have the same problem.. could you please tell me what you did, pls?

Comment: Check your CORS.